# Adding class to div with onclick function

Tags: javascript

I tried to find some way to solve my problem, which is to add class to the `div`s when I click on them, but I can't make it work.

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('applications');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (el[i]) {
      el[i].className += el[i].className ? ' openDiv' : 'openDiv';
    }
  });
}
```

I have the 'for loop' because I used `getElementsByClassName` which gives a node list. I also created a codepen example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGqmMy

Comment: It looks suspiciously like you'll have trouble with closures, if you alert the value of `i` in your method you might find it is always `el.length` or undefined

Comment: inside the `addEventListener`, `el[i]` is undefined (when clicked).  closures indeed.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lo2zrsqs/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using complex string manipulation, use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
el[i].classList.add('openDiv');
```

I believe you might need to add a closure for the eventListeners to work.

So this would be considered as a solution:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('applications');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    el[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (el[i]) {
        el[i].classList.add('openDiv');
      }
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it anyway answers the problem... could be suggestion to make the existing code better...

Comment: @ArunPJohny I was... Okay.. I was suggesting the right way, because that might not work. I also said that using closures will work. But haven't provided the code.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I guess `if (el[i]) {` is not playing any role here, perhaps adding confusion..

Comment: @RayonDabre Yeah, one thing is, it looks like that person is actually checking whether that element exists or not. Good thing only right?

Comment: If element does not exist, will `addEventListener` invoke handler ? _Note:_ `el.classList.contains('openDiv')` will needed as OP is trying to do toggle classes..I also feel, `forEach` would look pretty than `closure` ;)

Comment: @RayonDabre Yeah, looks right... Let's see what's OP is upto. Should definitely come back if they have issues. So they will surely check the comments. Let's see. Thanks for the insights though! `:)`